# Uploading multiple small files to a PHP server and DDoS attacks

Tags: php, ajax, performance, security

Let's say I have a web app installed in a **shared hosting** and **1M user** online.

If users were to upload a bunch of small files ( let's say a 1000 file, and the size of each file is approximately 100Kb ) **successively** and **at the same time**, using **multiple AJAX requests**,
Would this have the same effect as a **DDoS attack** ( so, it'll overwhelm the server) ?

Comment: That's the equivalent of 10MB of data, so no probably not considering people upload 10MB files to websites all the time which can be pretty much instantly. DDoS attacks would be much higher, I've seen as low as 100MB **_per second_**, and have heard of times where the attacker was sending over 1GB (1024MB)/s

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton and let's say we have 1M user online and uploading at the same time

Comment: That would cause a `DoS`. Your last comment. But if you have 1M users, you will have more servers than one. So hard to say.

Comment: Well that entirely depends on your server. If your server can handle that many people online at once (which I very very very highly doubt), then a 10MB upload should not even be noticable to anyone.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I updated the question with more infos .

Comment: @AjAX I updated the question with more infos .

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thank you so much, so it depends on the server? right ?

Comment: @AjAX. Thanks a million , could you post this comment as an answer , it seems this is the best one .

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Done.

Comment: @CryptoBird That is correct. However, even with a really really low end server, it would very likely be able to handle a 10MB upload.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton What would I do without you, this is the answer that I'm looking for , you just hit the bullseye , actually, I'm trying to see if is there any chance to handle that in a low end server . You are AWESOME .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let’s say it depends on your headroom.

If you really have 1 server.

It may be possible to have 1M users logged in.

[But a server like Node.js can handle maximum 1M concurrent connections.](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/08/19/node-js-w1m-concurrent-connections/)

So if these 1M go, everything is DoSed in second 1.

It all depends on the available concurrent connections.

It is — not — about the file size in this example.

Comment: Thanks man and special thanks to @GrumpyCrouton too , you guys are awesome .